# What kind of edits are accepted here?

Tags: discussion, editing

Out of [five edit](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/5009/theta30?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) suggestions, only [one](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/5009/theta30?tab=activity&sort=revisions) was approved. That is 20%, a very low percentage.
 Since I am not a cooking expert, but I like editing English, I thought that's an useful way to get points. Note that you spend some time to edit. I feel like I am blocked to do edits, or that the policy is a tolerance for English errors.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think I can actually see the rejection reasons used for your edits, but I strongly suspect that most of yours were rejected as *too minor*.

The description basically explains it:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be **substantive improvements** addressing **multiple issues** in the post.

(emphasis mine)

It's not that we don't like to see proper spelling, grammar, and punctuation. We do. Some of us (myself included) are veritable sticklers for this in regard our own posts and will often rewrite other people's posts completely (or at least the titles) to make them coherent.

However, adding a few apostrophes to the word "its" really does not go a long way toward making the post more clear or readable.

If somebody's writing style is absolutely atrocious, please, fix it. But don't nit pick over image sizes or italicization of terms. I'm sure your intentions are entirely positive but to most of us it appears to be editing just for the sake of editing.

*Most* edits here are, in fact, approved. Yossarian approves about 2/3 of edits, I've approved over 80% of the ones I've seen. An edit really has to be quite trivial or even wrong in order to be rejected.

Here are two examples of recent, quality suggested edits that were approved:

- [Example 1](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/537)
- [Example 2](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/532)

As you can see, these both include significant changes and make the posts far more concise and readable.

By far the most effective way to get your edit *rejected* is to correct very minor issues *while leaving behind major ones*. Examples would be fixing a few capitalization or punctuation problems in posts that (still) have several grammatical errors or worse, are factually incorrect or even nonsensical walls-of-text.

If you don't wish to have your edits scrutinzed this way, then contribute quality answers (or questions) until you have 2k reputation; then you can edit freely without your edits needing to be approved.

Comment: Also note that I believe the reason the one edit was approved was due to the misspelling on Fondue. Since the misspelling might cause confusion as exactly what the OP meant, the correction on the spelling affected the post substantial enough for it to be approved. The other 4 edits were minor apostrophe and capitalization edits.

Comment: I probably would have rejected the one that was accepted, too; the accept came from another member who almost never rejects. The problem with that edit is, as I've mentioned above, that it corrects minor errors while ignoring major ones, such as (a) the title not being a complete sentence and (b) the body not actually containing a direct question. But it's closed anyway so it's a moot point.

Comment: @Theta30, by no means do I have the best edits but I've gotten all my edits approved so far so if I'm sure I'm doing something right. You can take a look at the type of edits I've made in the past: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/8305/jay?tab=activity&sort=suggestions